# Is there a way in typescript to specify that a type paremeter is itself generic?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've got a bunch of types that follow a consistent pattern:

```
Foo<X> & Foo<Y>
Bar<X> & Bar<Y>
Baz<X> & Baz<Y>
```

(Where X and Y are the same two types each time.)

There's a clear pattern here, and I'd like to extract a generic type for it, along the lines of `type WrapBoth<W> = W<X> & W<Y>` to transform this into

```
WrapBoth<Foo>
WrapBoth<Bar>
WrapBoth<Baz>
```

As written, this produces the error `W is not generic` (which is to be expected; I haven't specified that it is).

My issue is that I can't see a way to specify that `W` should be "any type that accepts exactly one type parameter, which I will specify when I use it".

Is there any way of specifying this, or is it simply not supported?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly, what do you mean exactly by  "any type that accepts exactly one type parameter"?

if you use 'any' type it will literally be anything, but I don't think that's what you want, if you want it to be a specific type you can do something like

`type a = b | c`

Comment: In the above cases Foo, Bar and Baz are all generic types with one type paramenter. They would be declared along the lines of: `type Foo<T> = ...` (or `interface Foo<T>`).

Comment: It is not possible at the moment but there is an open issue on TypeScript github https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213

Comment: Ah, that's an answer at least (even if it's not one I'd prefer!)

What's the etiquette on something like that as an answer? If you want to write it up, I'd be happy to accept it as answering the question for now.